# Ionic build error Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using ionic and cordova in my project but am getting the above error, yet when I try to search online, all the solutions include google firebase, yet I am not using anything from firebase. The project has been building successfully but the error just came from now where.
Here is the error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
   Searched Location:
  D:\Projects\Twalako\apps\driver\platforms\android\app\src\nullnull\google-services.json
  D:\Projects\Twalako\apps\driver\platforms\android\app\src\debug\google-services.json
  D:\Projects\Twalako\apps\driver\platforms\android\app\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
  D:\Projects\Twalako\apps\driver\platforms\android\app\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
  D:\Projects\Twalako\apps\driver\platforms\android\app\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
  D:\Projects\Twalako\apps\driver\platforms\android\app\google-services.json

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Ionic info

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.12.1 (C:\Users\Evans\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 2.4.0
   @capacitor/core : 2.4.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 22 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res                          : 0.15.2
   native-run (update available: 1.0.0) : 0.2.8

System:

   NodeJS : v14.15.4 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.10
   OS     : Windows 10
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "driver",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "2.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/badge": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/call-number": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/crop": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/location-accuracy": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/native-geocoder": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.30.0",
    "@ionic-native/sms-retriever": "^5.28.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.3.1",
    "call-number": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-androidx-build": "^1.0.4",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "^1.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-badge": "^0.8.8",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-crop": "^0.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps.git#multiple_maps",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": "^3.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": "^2.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-sms-retriever-manager": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "^1.4.1",
    "cupertino-pane": "git+https://github.com/roman-rr/cupertino-pane.git",
    "ionic-selectable": "^4.7.1",
    "ng-otp-input": "^1.7.1",
    "ngx-ion-simple-mask": "^0.8.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "2.4.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.13",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-sms-retriever-manager": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "15.0.1"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-crop": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder": {},
      "mx.ferreyra.callnumber": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {},
      "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_LOCATION_VERSION": "16.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-badge": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give list of dependency used in your app ? you can find it in package.json file.

Comment: I have added the package.json file @CodeChanger

Comment: add `google-services.json` in android/app folder

Comment: you are using `cordova-support-google-services` plugin

Check this link 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-support-google-services'

Comment: Where do I get the google-services.json file if am not using firebase @RaviAshara?

Comment: Create project in firebase 'https://console.firebase.google.com/' with you package name and Appname and set with android platform

Comment: check this link for setup step 'https://enappd.com/blog/connect-firebase-with-ionic-5-app/134/'

Comment: I do not intend to use firebase and I do not want to use it, so I do not know if I still need to include it much as I do not need it.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `cordova-support-google-services` for Google Play services so you need to add `google-service.json` file into your root folder.

To get this file logged in into google console (https://console.firebase.google.com/)

1. Create New Project / Open Existing Project.
2. Go to Project Setting & Add/Open Android platform.
3. Download `google-service.json` file from there.

Screenshot from the google console:
[image]

Add downloaded file to your app root directory.

Project view & file on Visual studio:
[image]

Hope this will help you to rid out of google service error.

Thanks!

Comment: At one time I used firebase and later removed it completely from my project and I no longer use or need it. What do I need to do to get rid of this error if I do not intend to use firebase?

Comment: In that case, you need to remove all related plugins and clean your project, and rebuilt again. Also if you are not using google service then remove that plugin also.

Comment: I finally got rid of the error by removing the cordova-support-google-services plugin, and everything is now okay, thanks for your assistance.